# pyqt how to make application truly active

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt4

Under OS X, using the zetcode [example for menubar](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/menusandtoolbars/), if one runs this from the command line:

```
$ python menubar.py
```

the application starts, but at the bottom of the window stack. This can be fixed by adding
    self.raise_()

to the code.

However, the application is still not immediately active. The terminal application menubar still shows, not the pyqt menubar.

The only way to get the pyqt menubar to show is to switch away from the pyqt application or terminal application and back again.

Is this expected behavior? Is there anyway to fix this so the pyqt application immediately becomes active, i.e. the pyqt menubar immediately shows upon execution.

Versions: OS X 10.9, Qt 4.8.6, PyQt 4.11.3, SIP 4.16.5, python 2.7.8

Comment: Have you tried [`activateWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#activateWindow)? Also, what happens if you launch the app as a bg process: i.e. `python menubar.py &`?

Comment: See comments in answer below. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The identical problem affects some apps bundled by PyInstaller. The following blog post discusses the fix, however the fix is in terms of the PyInstaller boot loader, which would not be directly relevant to your code, but it might be informative.

http://dvitonis.net/blog/2015/01/07/menu-bar-not-visible-when-building-pyqt-app-bundle-pyinstaller-mac-osx-mavericks-yosemite/

The problem relates to use of TransformProcessType() which is discussed in this linked article:

http://www.sheepsystems.com/developers_blog/TPT-show-menu.html

I do not know what Qt method would relate to the Mac OS TransformProcessType() but you might experiment with calling QWidget.setWindowState() in your mainwindow's __init__().

Comment: I have an app bundled with PyInstaller that has exactly this issue on OS X Yosemite: when launched it is the frontmost window but the menubar is still that of the Terminal, and I have to click another app and then back to mine for its menubar to take effect. I have tried all the following after the my_main_window.show() call: my_main_window.activateWindow() and my_main_window.raise_() and my_main_window.setWindowState( Qt.WindowActive ). None had any effect.

Comment: Playing with setWindowState and various WindowFlag settings have not worked. And there appears to be no direct info from the pyqt mailing list itself. So, there seems to be inherent in the system, at least with OS X.

Comment: @triccare. There's really not much point posting to the PyQt mailing list, unless someone reading it happens to have had the same issue and discovered a solution. This is almost certainly a Qt-specific issue, so you need try their bugtracker (although the current status of [QTBUG-28327](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28327) doesn't seem to offer much hope).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this behavior, but only when I launch with a `--nosplash` option to skip the splash screen in my application.

That gave me a hint, and I developed this workaround using a 'dummy' splash screen:

```
widget = QtGui.QMainWindow() # or whatever your main window class is
dummy = QtGui.QSplashScreen()
dummy.show()
dummy.finish(widget)
widget.show()
widget.raise_()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out in the near future.